# .NET Core EF relations

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I tries to figured it out why this is not wokring and getting me:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The relationship from
> 'Meeting.MeetingType' to 'MeetingType.Meeting' with foreign key
> properties {'MeetingId' : string} cannot target the primary key
> {'MeetingTypeId' : int} because it is not compatible. Configure a
> principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this
> relationship.

I want to have that `Meeting` can have one `MeetingType` but `MeetingTypes` can have many meetings

Meeting

```
public class Meeting {
    public string MeetingId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? MeetingDate { get; set; }
    public int MeetingTypeId { get; set; }
    public MeetingType MeetingType { get; set; }
    public Int64 StudyId{ get; set; }
    public Study Study{ get; set; }
}
```

Meeting Type

```
public class MeetingType {
    public int MeetingTypeId { get; set; }
    public string MeetingTypeName { get; set; }
    public Meeting Meeting {get; set;}
}
```

Context

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MeetingType> (entity => {
    entity.ToTable ("MeetingType", "tabel")
        .HasOne (x => x.Meeting)
        .WithOne (x => x.MeetingType)
        .HasForeignKey<Meeting> (x => x.MeetingId);
});

modelBuilder.Entity<Meeting> (entity => {
    entity.ToTable ("Meeting", "tabel")
        .HasOne (x => x.Study)
        .WithMany (x => x.Meeting)
        .HasForeignKey (x => x.StudyId);
});
```

Comment: This line `.HasForeignKey<Meeting> (x => x.MeetingId);` should be `.HasForeignKey<Meeting> (x => x.MeetingTypeId);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your class:

```
public class MeetingType {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Meeting> Meetings {get; set;}
    }
```

and db context ( if you use EF Net5 you don't need to use it):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Meeting>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.MeetingType)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Meetings)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.MeetingTypeId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Change the foreign key from MeetingId to MeetingTypeId

```
`modelBuilder.Entity<MeetingType>(entity => {
            entity.ToTable("MeetingType", "tabel")
           .HasOne(x => x.Meeting)
           .WithOne(x => x.MeetingType)
           .HasForeignKey<Meeting>(x => x.MeetingTypeId);
        });`
```